# Android MVVM + Databinding, does following code hold reference to View/Activity/Context causing a leak?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I am going to ask multiple questions, if it's not allowed please let me know I will remove them the main question is that...

In which cases `ViewModel` potentially cause a leak or maybe defy use of MVVM? (Please recommended reliable MVVM project(s) for review if possible)

```
import ....View;     //Question 1
import ....Activity;

public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    // Question 2
    public void viewClicked(View v){
        ((TextView)v).setText("Clicked")
    }
}
```

In some `layout.xml`

```
<layout>

    <import "android.app.Activity"/>  //Question 3

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="MyViewModel"/>

    <TextView  // Question 4
        ....
        ....
        android:onClick='@{viewModel::viewClicked}'/>

    <Button  //Question 5
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        ....
        ....
        android:onClick='@{() -> ((Activity)btnBack.getContext()).finish()}'/>

</layout>
```

Question 1:
Do import statements of Activity cause memory leak?

Question 2:
Why is `viewClicked` type method not recommended in ViewModel when it helps in View Handling.

Questions 2.1:
This is Java 101 knowledge, but still. Does ViewModel method with View as argument make entire ViewModel hold reference to View/Context as people are more agressive against these type of methods.?

Question 3:
Can import of Activity in Databinding XML cause problem?

Question 4:
If not in viewmodel where should click logic in Databinding be placed in MVVM?

Question 5:
Should you do this (see Button onClick) as you can simply call finish method right from XML when you know back button is always going to kill activity.

Comment: I think you should be looking at the generated source code from the databinding library - this xml is just an abstraction over generated source code at compile time. I would avoid having any Android classes, especially an `Activity` reference. A ViewModel should not hold a direct reference to the view - hence the data binding, unlike MVP.  ViewModel's have a longer lifecycle than instances of an `Activity` - `ViewModel::onCleared` is only called if the `Activity` is not being re created (configuration change) and is finishing.

Answer (score 0):

1) An import statement in code by itself don't really do anything.  It's just a way for the compiler to resolve class namespaces.  The JVM won't really load an imported class into memory unless the class is referenced the code.

2) A ViewModel class is meant to hold observable data that is relevant to the rendering of your UI.  Its data should be observed by the UI (e.g. through [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding))  but in itself should have no direct references of the specific widgets and views that make it up.  In general a ViewModel should have no Android class references at all.

2.1) Any reference to a View holds a reference to the enclosing context/Activity.  This is why in general, it is bad practice to hold a reference to a view in any piece of code that might exceed the lifecycle of an Activity (e.g. non-static AsyncTasks, background thread callbacks etc.).  I believe there's a specific lint check that against holding Views in ViewModels.

3) 4) 5) Don't import the Activity itself, but not for memory leak reasons.  Your views should ideally just observe the ViewModels.   Look at this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#5) on having ViewModels respond to events.  If you need to invoke Activity methods, remember your Activities can observe ViewModels too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 2.1: Not having View declared in VM but just a method can have it hold the reference?  Also where does clicks etc logic go then?

Comment: Maybe it can, I've never tried it, but you avoid it.  The point with ViewModels is to hold state.  Your Views will observe the data in the ViewModels (using databinding) and update themselves when the data changes.  As for handling events, you can have our view onClick in the layout call a method in the ViewModel which modifies the data.  And since Views observe data inside the model, they update themselves without you have to explicitly call setter methods.  Check out the codelab I linked, that's exactly what they do.